# Change file name according to its parent's name

Tags: bash

Hi everyone I have several files such as:

`/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPA_1/run_ok/single
/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPB_2/run_ok/single
/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPC_3/run_ok/single`

and I would like to change the run_ok names depending of their parent's name and get:

`/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPA_1/run_ok_SPA_1/single
/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPB_2/run_ok_SPB_2/single
/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPC_3/run_ok_SPC_3/single`

Does someone have an idea,
Thank you.

In fact first to extract the SPA_1 part from:

`/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPA_1/run_Ok/single/`

and put it into a sppname variable.
I tried:

`file="/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPA_1/run_X/single/"; sppname=$(basename $(dirname "$file")); echo "$sppname"`

I should gate then: 
SPA_1

but it does not work. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try yet? Find files by name, iterate over each, extract parent name, rename. 5 lines of code.

Comment: I updated my post thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using sed with backreferences:

```
for file in /path1/path2/path3/M2/*/*/*; 
do 
    mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(\/.*\/.*\/.*\/\)\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/single/\1\3_\2\/single/'`; 
done;
```

The `\1`, `\2` and `\3` get replaced by the first part of the path, the filename and the directory you want, respectively. They are matched between the `\(\)` in the pattern.

To understand backreferences you can play with this simpler example. The basic search command in sed is `s/SEARCH/REPLACE/`. Notice that here we are dealing with directories so every slash `/` has been escaped with a backslash `\/`:

```
echo $file | sed 's/\/path1\/path2\/path3\/M2\/\(.*\)\/single/\1/';
```

This will give you the `SPA_1` portion of the string. It is matched with this part of the pattern: `\(.*\)`, and in the replacement it's `\1` (match no. 1)

Comment: Humm, in order to better inderstand, could you first tell me how to isolate a part of a path, lets say I have `/path1/path2/path3/M2/SPA_1/run_Ok/single/`, and I want to isolate `SPA_1` ?

Comment: Added explanation and updated the command with the new paths you put in your question. Hop this helps.

Comment: Ok I see, and what if I do not want to replace but instead only display the part of the path, for instance let say I have `/Users/admin/Documents/Acromyrmex_achinatior/busco_run/run_BUSCO_v3/single_copy_busco_sequences` and I would like to only display `Acromyrmex_achinatior` I think it would help me do deal with path moves

Comment: Try this: `echo '/Users/admin/Documents/Acromyrmex_achinatior/busco_run/run_BUSCO_v3/single_copy_busco_sequences' | sed 's/\/Users\/admin\/Documents\/\([^\/]*\)\/.*/\1/'`. The backreference part `\([^\/]*\)` means "anything that is not a /"

Comment: yes but sed is to replace is not it ? I only want here (to better understand) to echo the `Acromyrmex_achinatior` part from the all path nothing else...  for exemple put `Acromyrmex_achinatior`  into a sppname by doing file="/Users/admin/Documents/busco_run_Acromyrmex_achinatior/single_copy_busco_sequences/"; sppname=$( go to Acromyrmex_achinatio part from "$file); echo "$sppname"

Comment: Then simply assign the command output to a variable: `sppname=$(echo '/Users/admin/Documents/Acromyrmex_achinatior/busco_run/run_BUSCO_v3/single_copy_busco_sequences' | sed 's/\/Users\/admin\/Documents\/\([^\/]*\)\/.*/\1/')`, and then `echo $sppname`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rename the directory `run_ok`; the contents of `run_ok` aren't relevant.

```
cd /path1/path2/path3/M2 &&
  for d in */; do
    [ -d "$d"/run_ok ] && mv -- "$d"/run_ok "$d"/"run_ok_$d"
  done
```

Comment: basename is a much simpler solution than the sed-based ones.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that `basename` isn't necessary, either, if you change directories first.